# Find median of 9 values with minimal levels of comparison

Tags: arrays, median

I'm trying to find a median of a 9-values array with as less levels of comparison as possible.
Hence, I'm searching for the most parallel way to do it (that takes the fact that it's only 9 values into account).
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This code can find the median of any number of numbers (sorry if that's confusing).

```
function sortNumber(a,b) {
  return a - b;
}
let numbersList = [];             // plug in numbers
numbersList.sort(sortNumber);
let a = numbersList.length
let b = (a + 1) / 2
console.log(numbersList[b - 1]);
```